# Is it possible to subset a classification task in mlr keeping the positive/negative class ratio unchanged?

Tags: mlr

In order to make small tests on a large machine learning classification task in mlr, I would like to create small tasks first that maintain the positive/negative ratio of the original task.

Currently I am doing this manually using the function `subsetTask` setting the argument `subset` to a fixed index vector that preserves the class ratio.

Is there any way to do this internally? something like "Take 75% of this task, preserving the class ratio". Maybe using a resampling instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `downsample(my_task, perc=0.05, stratify=TRUE)` should be what you're looking for:

https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/downsample.html

Setting the argument `stratify` to TRUE (it defaults to FALSE) keeps the class ratios of the original data.

Does that help?

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much! And sorry for answering you so late